# FacebookSDK(4.1.x) Custom Login UI Button - Swift(1.2)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

Following [this tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/), I have managed to make a Facebook Login Button working. However, it is assigning the button image automatically from the SDK and it is not customisable (as it is not getting created on Storyboard), so I am unable to use my own button image or text instead.

I believe this part of the code (in ViewDidLoad) is assigning the button:

```
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        loginView.delegate = self
```

What I need to do is creating a @IBOutlet Button on Storyboard and customise it from there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Login with custom button and access token.

Get user info in facebook sdk 4.x

### Swift

```
@IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                println(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: containsObject part gives an error: `'Set<NSObject>' does not have a member named 'containsObject'` ****Found the answer: change `containsObject` to `contains`

Comment: change the code : if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions..contains("email") { } @senty

Comment: Nice, What is the fbLoginManager.logOut() for?

Comment: But I mean why do we want to logout from the facebook session when we've just logged in?

Comment: I've just tested it and having the login on the button actually looses the accessToken as soon as you login so if the user kills the app, they have to login again.

Comment: if you need access token until the logout then remove that line `fbLoginManager.logout()` @lennard

Comment: what if the `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()` is `nil`? @DharmeshDhorajiya

Comment: modify result check to avoid error "got nil while unwrapping an optional" in case user cancel instead of Ok when Facebook dialog shows "You already authorized ... ". 
Use ```if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil && fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"){``` instead of just trying to see of grantedPermissions contains email

Comment: as of July 2016, logInWithReadPermissions should include viewController. So modify ```fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in``` to ```fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(permissions, fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in```. Check @SantosRamon's answer for reference

Answer (score 7):

Updated answer using the last Facebook SDK (01/05/2016) and Swift 2.1

Create a UIButton with Interface Builder or by code and  link the action of that button with this:

```
@IBAction func loginFacebookAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The happy case of the previous code triggers the function self.getFBUserData() so you have to implement that function in the same file

```
func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                //everything works print the user data
                print(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: modify result check to avoid error "got nil while unwrapping an optional" in case user cancel instead of Ok when Facebook dialog shows "You already authorized ... ". Use if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil && fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"){ instead of just trying to see of grantedPermissions contains email

Answer (score 2):

I did it successfully in xcode 7.3

```
    @IBAction func fbLoginBtnAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: {(result, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("Logged in through facebook" )
                self.getFBUserData()
            }
            else {
                print("Facebook Login Error----\n",error)
            }
        }
    )
}


  func getFBUserData () {
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                print(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reusable class (Swift 4).

Usage: `FacebookSignIn.shared.signIn(from: yourVC, completion: yourCompletion)`

```
class FacebookSignIn {

   enum Error: Swift.Error {
      case unableToInitializeGraphRequest
      case unexpectedGraphResponse
      case permissionsIsNotGranted
      case unexpectedLoginResponse
      case canceled
   }

   struct Permissions {

      static let email = "email"
      static let profile = "public_profile"

      static func isValidPermissions(_ permissions: Set<AnyHashable>) -> Bool {
         return permissions.contains(email) && permissions.contains(profile)
      }

      static var permissions: [String] {
         return [email, profile]
      }
   }

   public static let shared = FacebookSignIn()

   private init() {
   }

}

extension FacebookSignIn {

   func signIn(from: UIViewController, completion: Result<SignInResponse>.Completion?) {
      let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()
      manager.loginBehavior = .native
      if !isValidToken {
         manager.logOut()
      }
      if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current() {
         let interval = token.expirationDate.timeIntervalSince(Date())
         if interval > 300 { // At least 5 min token will be valid
            performLogin {
               switch $0 {
               case .failure(let error):
                  completion?(.failure(error))
               case .success(let info):
                  completion?(.success(SignInResponse(accessToken: token.tokenString, userInfo: info)))
               }
            }
         } else {
            FBSDKAccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken { [weak self] _, _, error in
               if let error = error {
                  manager.logOut()
                  completion?(.failure(error))
               } else {
                  let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current()?.tokenString ?? "" // Should be always valid value at this point.
                  self?.performLogin {
                     switch $0 {
                     case .failure(let error):
                        completion?(.failure(error))
                     case .success(let info):
                        completion?(.success(SignInResponse(accessToken: token, userInfo: info)))
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      } else {
         manager.logIn(withReadPermissions: Permissions.permissions, from: from) { [weak self] result, error in
            if let error = error {
               manager.logOut()
               completion?(.failure(error))
               return
            }
            guard let result = result else {
               manager.logOut()
               completion?(.failure(Error.unexpectedLoginResponse))
               return
            }
            let permissions = result.grantedPermissions ?? Set<AnyHashable>()
            let token = result.token?.tokenString ?? "" // Should be always valid value at this point.
            if result.isCancelled {
               manager.logOut()
               completion?(.failure(Error.canceled))
            } else if Permissions.isValidPermissions(permissions) {
               self?.performLogin {
                  switch $0 {
                  case .failure(let error):
                     completion?(.failure(error))
                  case .success(let info):
                     completion?(.success(SignInResponse(accessToken: token, userInfo: info)))
                  }
               }
            } else {
               manager.logOut()
               completion?(.failure(Error.permissionsIsNotGranted))
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private var isValidToken: Bool {
      guard let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current() else {
         return false
      }
      return Permissions.isValidPermissions(token.permissions ?? Set<AnyHashable>())
   }

   private func makeGraphRequest() -> FBSDKGraphRequest? {
      guard FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString != nil else {
         return nil
      }
      // You might not get email: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4
      // Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example,
      // if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.
      let fields = "email,id,first_name,last_name,gender"
      return FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": fields])
   }

   private func performLogin(completion: Result<[String: String]>.Completion?) {
      let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()
      guard let request = makeGraphRequest() else {
         manager.logOut()
         completion?(.failure(Error.unableToInitializeGraphRequest))
         return
      }
      _ = request.start { _, result, error in
         if let e = error {
            manager.logOut()
            completion?(.failure(e))
         } else if let result = result as? [String: String] {
            completion?(.success((result)))
         } else {
            manager.logOut()
            completion?(.failure(Error.unexpectedGraphResponse))
         }
      }
   }

}
```

---

```
public struct SignInResponse {

   public let accessToken: String
   public let userInfo: [String: String]

   public init(accessToken: String, userInfo: [String: String]) {
      self.accessToken = accessToken
      self.userInfo = userInfo
   }
}


public enum Result<T> {

   case success(T)
   case failure(Swift.Error)

   public typealias Completion = (Result<T>) -> Void
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the native button try this out:

```
let buttonText = NSAttributedString(string: "your text here")
facebookButton.setAttributedTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2017, the accepted answer updated for Swift 3 and latest version of FBSDK, the code looks like below-

```
@IBAction func fbLoginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let fbLoginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let fbLoginResult = result {
                    if fbLoginResult.grantedPermissions != nil && fbLoginResult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"){
                        self.getFBUserdata()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getFBUserdata(){
        if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil{
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,name,first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (cnnection, result, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    print(result ?? "Error in getFBUserdata function")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```