# Swift 2.0 working Facebook custom login button

Tags: facebook, swift2, access-token

I beg all of thee. I searched everywhere but i can't find working swift 2.0 code for Facebook custom login button with returning Access Token. My code simply don't work. (token is not returning Facebook token)

Comment: refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634269/facebooksdk4-1-x-custom-login-ui-button-swift1-2 , i used the accepted answer in this question and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have done all the setup as described by the Facebook developer page, you need to do the following in your login view controller:

// Import the following on top below "import UIKit" in your login view controller

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

// This is your action code for your custom login button for login using facebook in Swift

```
@IBAction func fbLoginBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let permisions = ["public_profile", "email"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permisions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let user = user {
                print(user)

            // "yourSegue" below will be the segue identifier for your new view.
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegue", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case you have not setup your app at Facebook developer, please following the simple steps as mentioned in [Facebook Developer Page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).

Comment: do I need import something else? it gives me an err
` Use of unresolved identifier 'PFFacebookUtils'`

Comment: Did you import #import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h> in your bridging header? And what version of Parse and Facebook SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Add a normal button in your view then add the FB login class "FBSDKLoginButton" 
2 - Declare your button in your ViewController

```
 @IBOutlet weak var FBLoginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!
```

3 - Add in your ViewDidload methode

```
if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }
    else
    {

      self.FBLoginButton.delegate = self

        FBLoginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    }
```

4-Add Delegate Login and logout button funcutions

```
   func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
```

loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

```
    let fbAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me?fields=id,name,email,gender,first_name,last_name,middle_name,birthday&access_token=\(fbAccessToken)", parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            // Process error
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("fetched user: \(result)")

        }


})
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("User Logged Out")
}
```