# Swift FBSDKLoginButton How do I edit the Title button on Facebook?

Tags: swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

How do I change the title?

```
class LoginController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{


@IBOutlet var btnFacebook: FBSDKLoginButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureFacebook()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func configureFacebook()
{
    btnFacebook.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"];

    btnFacebook.delegate = self
    btnFacebook.setTitle("test", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to make custom button for the facebook login? this may help you: 
[Official facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#custom-login-button) you can convert that in the swift if you want

Or for swift you can use this code with any custom button: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34615159/4557505)

```
@IBAction func loginFacebookAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    GAnalytics.registerClick("Login Facebook", screen: self.className)
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                print(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```