# custom button with image for FBSDKLoginButton

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook, swift2

i want use a custom button with image ,

I don't want to use Facebook default login button.

this is my code

```
    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    loginButton.center = self.view.center
    loginButton.delegate = self
    loginButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "cyanx2")
    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

and my button would be

```
@IBAction func customButton(sender: UIButton) {

 // here's go the action when click on default facebook button   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30634444/5576310) post

i fix my problem ^_^ and this is the code

button function

```
@IBAction func loginFacebookAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            NSLog("Process error")
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            NSLog("Cancelled")
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Logged in")
            self.getFBUserData()
        }

    }
}
```

function to fetch the result from facebook

```
 func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    //everything works print the user data
                    print(result)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```